# Check if YouTube User Exists with PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube, args

Okay so I'm trying to redirect a user back to subto.me.com if subto.me/args doesn't exist I have this code

```
if(file_exists($BASEPATH."partials/".$request['args'][0].".php")) {
            require($BASEPATH."partials/".$request['args'][0].".php");
        } else {
            header("Location: http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=".$request['args'][0]);
        }
```

If the youtube user doesn't exist, it will say so using a link like this https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/fdsafsdfasdfasd. How would I incooperate it if source code equals "User not found"

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for that:

```
$yuser = "http://www.youtube.com/user/xxxx";
$yt_headers = @get_headers($yuser);
if($yt_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')
{ echo "Youtube user dosen't exist"; }
else { echo "Youtube user exists"; }
```

this can be used as a function to make the process more pretty!